# C/C++ Unix configuration file library

Tags: c++, c, unix, configuration-files

Where can I find a C or C++ library for reading and manipulating Unix configuration files (`format: name=value\n`)?

Comment: The C (or C++) Standard Library?

Comment: I'm sure someone will mention `boost::program_options` for C++ and `getopt` for C.

Comment: Sorry this might sound like a stupid question, i am very new to C/C++.

Comment: I am writing a programm for unix-ish systems. I need a simple config file which behaves as a *nix admin would expect.

Comment: http://ndevilla.free.fr/iniparser/

Comment: What would a Unix admin expect?  In my experience, Unix config files come in a variety of different formats.  Compare the Apache `httpd.conf` with `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: @JeremyP: see in my question (format: name=value\n). With 15 years of *nix experience, this seems to be fairly standard for dotfiles and config files in /etc (but sure, it's not the only solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For plain C, [libconfuse](https://github.com/martinh/libconfuse) is quite good

Comment: Interesting, looks similar to the format being used by puppetmaster for example.

Answer (score 6):

I will advice you to use boost::property_tree library for C++. It has quiet detailed manual. Further I'll advice you to use "info" config file.

Example of config file:

```
; this is just comment line

firstParamSection 
{
   stringParam "string"
   intParam 10
}
```

Example of code to retrieve this parameters from config file:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/info_parser.hpp>
#include <string>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::string testString;
  int testInt;

  boost::property_tree::ptree pTree;
  try {
    read_info("test/config/file/name", pTree);
  }
  catch (boost::property_tree::info_parser_error e) {
    std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
  }

  try {
    testString = pTree.get<std::string>("firstParamSection.stringParam");
    testInt = pTree.get<int>("firstParamSection.intParam");
  }

  catch(boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_path e) {
    std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
  }
```

Comment: If you want to use strcitly (name = "value") format boost supports it, too. Just use ini_parser instead of info_parser.

Comment: This seems to be the solution I was looking for. However, I figured that I will first roll my own solution (for educational purpose) and then switch to boost in later projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have written a config parser for "info" style config files myself a few weeks ago. It's fully XDG compliant, sections can be nested and it's pretty easy to use:

```
// read config file "barc" in directory $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/foo, e.g. /home/bwk/.config/foo/barc
config_read("foo", "barc");

// can read a specific file as well:
config_read_file("/etc/tralalarc");

// or from an open FILE *fp
config_read_fp(fp);

// or n characters directly from memory
config_read_mem(0xDEADBEEF, n);


// retrieve value associated with "key" in section "here", sub-section "my"
char *val = config_get("here.my.key");
```

You can also set/lock config variables including comments and write the config back to disk. It's pretty self-explaining, but it lacks documentation. See `config.*` [here](http://code.google.com/p/5dev/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Flib).

I'd be happy to add documentation and/or interface as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your example code. Because i am only a couple of days into C this will help me understand file and string handling.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Augeas](http://augeas.net/), its pretty universal.